# How many $\mathbb R$s must a Mathematician walk down?

Tags: complex-numbers, puzzle

A mathematician is lost on the complex plane. He knows neither his position nor the direction he is facing. He wants to return to the main road, a strip of width $1$ around the real axis (that is, from $\mathbb R+\frac{i}{2}$ to $\mathbb R-\frac{i}{2}$). Naturally, he will recognize the road once he is on it.

The only instrument in his possession is a compass-like device that can show him the absolute value $|z|$ of his position $z$. The problem: He bought the cheap "finite precision" version, which does not display any digits after the decimal point (it just rounds to the nearest integer).

Looking at his device, he sees the number $1000$. Can he get to his destination in a finite number of steps, where a step consists of consulting the device, turning an angle $\phi$ of his choice and then walking straight for a distance $d$ of his choice (both choices can be different in each step)? If yes, how can he minimize the number of steps he must take? Or is it all hopeless and in the end the answer is blowing in the wind?

*Clarification: He will recognize the road when a step takes him directly on to it. He will **not** recognize the road simply by crossing it in the course of a step.*

Comment: Is he allowed to  use his device along the way and react to the data accumulated?

Comment: @RossMillikan: He can use the device before and after every step and base his decision on its reading, but the "turn and walk" operation is atomic.

Comment: So he can never just go straight? Also, he presumably has a choice between $-\phi$ and $\phi$, right? Finally, what interval is $\phi$ in?

Comment: But are $\phi$ and $d$ fixed? Or can he change them from turn to turn, at will?

Comment: I don't feel like working out the details, but it seems to me like as long as he's quite far from the origin, he can just jump around a sufficiently dense subset of circle of radius $2$ around himself to get a rough idea about the direction in which he can find the origin. It gets more tricky when he gets somewhat close to origin, but then he can just jump around in a dense grid and eventually he'll get close enough.

Comment: Also, the problem is simpler to think about if we assume that he doesn't want to just get to the strip, but actually to the ball of radius half around the origin. The difficulty of this task is certainly not any smaller (and, on average, not much bigger, either).

Comment: The way I understand it he is not seeking to minimize the distance he needs to walk but rather the number of times he consults his device. And assuming he is capable of following a straight line, and can estimate the distance travelled accurately.

Comment: @tomasz In addition to what you've said, he is blind to where the real axis is; the data he has access to only helps him to find, roughly, the origin and concentric circles at integer distances from the origin.

Comment: Also, it's pretty easy to get "far" from the origin; If your meter currently reads $d$ and you want to get at least distance $N$ away from the origin, you just travel a distance of $N+2d$ in any direction.

Comment: The problem of the imprecision of the device can be removed at the price of a number of movements depending on the desired precision. Specifically, suppose your initial position is $z_0$; I will write $\| z \|$ for the device-measured distance to the origin at point $z$. Pick a unit complex number $y$ and take $z_1 = z_0 + 0.5y$. Then check whether $\| z_1 \|$ is different from $\| z_0 \|$. If it is, go to $z_2 = z_1 - 0.25y$, otherwise go to $z_2 = z_2 + 0.25y$. After $n$ steps of this, I think the device should be accurate to within $2^{-n}$.

Comment: Are there any land marks on the complex plane?

Comment: @dustin: No. (words to fill minimum length requirement)

Comment: I haven't confirmed the details but isn't this the solution: Step 1 needs to be a walk in any direction long enough to avoid rounding errors.  
Step 2 can then be towards one of the possible origins determined by the triangle implied by the two lengths towards it we now have.  
Step 3 (if needed) is to turn around and walk toward the correct origin if the wrong one was chosen before. (And you now have three lengths pointing to it.)

Answer (score 7):

He doesn't even need his special device to find the road in a finite time. He just needs to walk in an expanding spiral, in straight-line steps shorter than two units, until he hits the road.

The spiral can be any scale, but if he knows that he is 1000 units from the origin, it is enough to go forward 1000 units, left 1000 units, left 2000 units, left 2000 units, and left  again 2000 units, which takes at most 501 + 501 + 1001 + 1001 + 1001 = 4005 steps. (Of course this can be improved on, for instance by following a circle more closely.)

Comment: Good idea, though assuming a spiral based on a unit square grid and given his initial distance of $1000$, he might have to take up to *four million* steps to reach the road, and will probably starve first. My gut tells me it should be possible to reach the road in less than ten steps.

Comment: Good point. Actually, the strip is not special in any way: he can find his way into *any* open set, without any devices or even knowing what set this is: all he needs to do is to put an ${\bf R}^2$ grid on the space he's in, assuming his initial direction is the positive direction on $x$ axis, and then just jump around *all* rational numbers in succession. This becomes more tricky if we consider the problem in some non-euclidean space, but I think it should be doable, in principle, on any connected manifold.

Comment: @pew: I have updated my answer, to show that 4005 steps is enough. Of course this is not optimal, but it's better than four million!

Comment: @pew: My gut feeling is that four or five steps is enough, with the help of The Device.

Answer (score 3):

Since the problem statement says "he," may we assume the mathematician is not female?
That rules out one obvious answer that would get the mathematician back on the road in one step.

The initial reading tells the mathematician that the origin of the plane
is somewhere in an annulus with inner radius $999.5,$ outer radius $1000.5,$
and center at his current location.

The question is how efficiently he can subdivide the possible locations of the origin
until either he happens to land on the road while searching, or reduces the possible
locations of the origin to a figure that fits within a disk of radius $\frac12,$
at which point his next step is to travel to the center of that disk
(and he will then be on the road).

One method is to travel $10000$ units (or other suitably long distance)
in the initial direction. This narrows the location
of the origin either to a long, thin sliver between two arcs,
to a figure like a double-headed "spear" (with a bent or straight shaft),
or to a disconnected figure composed two regions each bounded by four arcs.
In any case, there are two extremal points of the figure that are as far apart
as any two points in that figure can be.

The mathematician's second step is $\frac12$ unit in the same direction. 
This effectively draws a curve "lengthwise" through the locus of the origin, 
and depending on whether the distance reading goes up by one or stays the same, 
the locus is reduced to the part on one side or the other of that curve. 
The remaining locus has a maximum width of about $\frac12,$ 
possibly more than $\frac12$ but certainly much less than $1.$
In particular, it is possible to construct a line (relative to the points already
visited) that passes within less than $\frac12$ unit of all points in the 
remaining locus of the origin.

The mathematician's third step is to a point on that line a great distance from the
nearest point of the locus of the origin, and his fourth step is a distance
$\frac12$ to another point on that line.

The locus of the origin is now bounded between one pair if arcs approximately
$\frac12$ unit apart, 
and also between a pair of arcs approximately $\frac12$ unit apart
and approximately "perpendicular" to the first pair.
The locus easily fits within a disk of radius $\frac12,$
so the fifth (and final) step is to any point in that locus.

I'm not entirely certain it can't be done in four or fewer steps.

Comment: "That rules out one obvious answer that would get the mathematician back on the road in one step." Now I'm really curious...

Comment: The first paragraph is not meant seriously, of course. http://www.egscomics.com/index.php?id=196

Answer (score 0):

I can do it in three.  Walk $10$ in the direction he is facing.  Turn $\frac \pi 2$ and walk $10$.  At least one of the two will show a change of at least $7$ units.  Use the arctangent of the two observations to determine the direction to the origin.  You can't be too far off, so walk that way $1500$ and he will hit the road.

Comment: I am skeptical about this, given the stated imprecision of The Device.

Comment: Note that he must *reach* the road in $n$ steps, not cross it while walking (he doesn't get to stop in between).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that he can at least *estimate* his angle to the origin pretty effectively with just one step: take a step of length 500 in whatever angle he happens to be facing, and consult the device for the new distance $d$. If O,A,B denote origin, old position, new position respectively, then he knows all the distances OA, AB, OB to reasonable precision (all the lengths have to be at least 500, so the relative error introduced by rounding should be small). Using the law of cosines he can estimate all the angles of this triangle, which would give him a decent estimate of his angle to the origin.

I don't know whether this estimate is actually good enough that just turning to face the estimated origin and taking a step of length OB will get him close to the origin, though -- seems that OB being large gives the error a chance to get multiplied as well.

edit: I guess this is basically the same as Ross Millikan's answer, but it saves a step

Comment: There must be two possible places for the origin, symmetrical about the step you just took. You need a third reading to determine which.

Comment: ah, good point.

Comment: I guess the point is that you've succeeded in estimating the angle $\theta$ you need to turn, but you still don't know whether you should turn $\theta$ left or $\theta$ right